# Object copying in Objective-C raises the error : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, copy

I'm playing around objects copying in Objective-C and I got the infamous `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

I created the `Person` class like this :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *familyName;
}
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *familyName;
@end
```

and implemented :

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize firstName, familyName;
-(NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@ %@", firstName, familyName];
}
@end
```

Then I use it in the main function :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *a = [[Person alloc] init];
        [a setFirstName:@"Foo"];
        [a setFamilyName:@"Bar"];
        NSLog(@"%@", a);
        Person *b = [a copy];
        NSLog(@"%@", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error raises when the instruction `[a copy]` is being executed.
Why this error ? My object inherits from the `NSObject` so, I thought it would call the following method :

```
-(id)copy{
    return [self copyWithZone:NULL]:
}
```

So why it doesn't work ? Can we say that object copying using the `copy` method doesn't work ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You have to add NSCopying protocol to your custom class and you need override copyWithZone: method:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    // Copying code here.
}
```

After that you can call copy on your object.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the answer. If my understanding is correct, I have to create manually the resulting object in the "copyWithZone" ? There is no "automatic" way to do it like in other languages ?

Comment: @Zakaria yes you right you have to create resulting object manually, there is no automatic way to do it in custom classes. This is straightforward and there are plenty examples online how to do that. Thanks.